# Am I right in this proof of a criterion for the nonsingularity of a conic curve?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, elliptic-curves, rational-numbers

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}$
This is an exercise in Silverman and Tate's Rational Points on Elliptic Curves:

> Let $\C$ be the conic given by the equation
>   $$ F(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0.$$
>   Let $\delta$ be the determinant
>   $$ \delta:=\begin{vmatrix}2a&b&d\\ b&2c&e\\ d&e&2f\end{vmatrix}.$$
>   Show that if $\delta\neq0$, then $\C$ has no singular points; i.e. no $(x,y)$ satisfy $F(x,y)=F_x(x,y)=F_y(x,y)=0$.

Here, $F_x$ and $F_y$ are the partial derivatives of $F$. I think I've already solved the problem, but am quite unsure of the proof, and hence I would appreciate if somone can check it for me. Here's my attempted proof. Because there's a $3\times 3$ whose determinant is being taken, this motivates the introduction of a third variable $z$, so I thought to define:
$$ G(x,y,z):=ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dxz+eyz+fz^2. $$
Note that $G(x,y,1)\equiv F(x,y)$ under this definition. Then consider the sequence of equations given by setting each partial derivative of $G$ to $0$:
$$\begin{cases}
G_x=2ax+by+dz=0,\\ G_y=bx+2cy+ez=0,\\G_z=dx+ey+2fz=0.
\end{cases}$$
Now if $\mathbf M$ is the matrix in the question, then $\delta=\det \mathbf M$, and we now have an equation of the form
$$\mathbf{Mx}=\mathbf 0,$$
which looks right! So we use the condition $\delta\neq 0$ we get $\mathbf x=\mathbf M^{-1}\mathbf 0=\mathbf 0$, hence $z=0$, *which is a contradiction, because we need $z=1$ for $(x,y)$ to be a singular point of $F(x,y)=G(x,y,1)$.*

I'm not confident of this last part in italics. Can I really just impose the restriction $z=1$ at the end? Also, maybe a bigger issue is, how can I just introduce the extra condition $G_z=0$, when that's not required (I think) for $F(x,y)$ to have singular point $(x,y)$? I never used the condition $F(x,y)=0$ either, which feels really fishy. Can someone help explaining if my steps were valid, and if not, what the right idea is?

Comment: Any word? I'm working on the same problem.